# Specifying truncation point in glmmTMB R package

Tags: r, truncate, glmmtmb

I am working with a large dataset that contains longitudinal data on gambling behavior of 184,113 participants. The data is based on complete tracking of electronic gambling behavior within a gambling operator. Gambling behavior data is aggregated on a monthly level, a total of 70 months. I have an ID variable separating participants, a time variable (months), as well as numerous gambling behavior variables such as active days played for given month, bets placed for given month, total losses for given month, etc. Participants vary in when they have been active gambling. One participant may have gambled at month 2, 3, 4, and 7, another participant at 3, 5, and 7, and a third at 23, 24, 48, 65 etc.

I am attempting to run a negative binomial 2 truncated model in glmmTMB and I am wondering how the package handles lack of 0. I have longitudinal data on gambling behavior, days played for each month (for a total of 70 months). The variable can take values between 1-31 (depending on month), there are no 0. Participants’ months with 0 are absent from dataset. Example of how data are structured with just two participants:

```
# Example variables and data frame in long form 

  # Includes id variable, time variable and example variable 

id <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2) 

time <- c(2, 3, 4, 7, 3, 5, 7) 

daysPlayed <- c(2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2) 

dfLong <- data.frame(id = id, time = time, daysPlayed = daysPlayed)
```

**My question: How do I specify where the truncation happens in glmmTMB?** Does it default to 0? I want to truncate 0 and have run the following code (I am going to compare models, the first one is a simple unconditional one):

```
DaysPlayedUnconditional <- glmmTMB(daysPlayed ~ 1 + (1 | id), dfLong, family = truncated_nbinom2)
```

Will it do the trick?

Comment: Didn't you already ask this on `r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org`, and I already answered it? https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2021q1/029248.html

Comment: Yep, I did. I posted it here before I saw your answer. I was unsure if I had mailed the list correctly. Thanks a lot! If its okey, I'll just copy paste your answer below in case anybody else wonders the same. From the list:



    " I'm not 100% clear on your question, but: glmmTMB *only* does
zero-truncation, not k-truncation with k>0, i.e. you can only specify
the model

   Prob(x==0) = 0
   Prob(x>0) = Prob(NBinom(x))/Prob(NBinom(x>0))

(terrible notation, but hopefully you get the idea)"

Comment: You're allowed (encouraged) to answer your own question, so I'd post that as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0):

From Ben Bolker through r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org:
"I'm not 100% clear on your question, but: glmmTMB only does zero-truncation, not k-truncation with k>0, i.e. you can only specify the model Prob(x==0) = 0 Prob(x>0) = Prob(NBinom(x))/Prob(NBinom(x>0)) (terrible notation, but hopefully you get the idea)"